# Write textview specific position on the imageview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

I want to write textview on the imageview at specific position. There are lots of answered like this question but those answers did not solve my question. To understand what I want to do please look theses pictures.
[image] 
[image]

I want to write textview on the paper part of image on android. I used the below code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
        android:src="@drawable/chef_welcome"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:text="@string/chef_welcome"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This solution works any screen size. When screen size is small it is ok. But when size is large then image is very small for screen. If I change

> layout_height="match_parent"

in this case textview change position relate to screen size. If I use margin in this case when screen size change again textview position change even I used dimensions xml files for different screen size. Do you have any solution? or suggestion

Comment: There is no such a thing as `wrap_parent`. And yes, your approach is gonna work. You just need to add `padding_bottom` values specific to the screen size you will be supporting (by making multiple `dimens.xml` files)

Comment: @verybadalloc thanks for "wrap_parent". using padding is not solution check this
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Comment: what do you want me to check?